# How to combine VaR graphics?

Tags: r, plot, var, risk-analysis

I want to programm a rolling Value at Risk by hand. So I don't want to use the VaR from the PerformanceAnalytics package. I want to plot after calculations against the log-returns of a time series. 
Input:

```
getSymbols('^GDAXI', src='yahoo', return.class='ts',from="2005-01-01", to="2015-01-01")
GDAXI.DE=GDAXI[ , "GDAXI.Close"]
log_r1=diff(log(GDAXI.DE)) #log_r1=data
alpha=0.95
```

The VaR function:

```
VatR=function(data, alpha)
{
x=diff(log(data))  
mu=mean(x)
sigma=sqrt(var(x))
quant=qnorm(alpha, mean=0, sd=1)
vatr=tail(data,n=1)*(1-exp((-sigma)*quant+mu))    
}

data=GDAXI.DE
alpha=0.95
t=125
l=(-1)*diff(data)  #if GDAXI used code must be changed here diff
loss=c(0,l)
ValueatRisk=matrix(rep(0),length(data),1)
violations=matrix(rep(0),length(data),1)
for(i in (t+1):length(data))
{
ValueatRisk[i]=VatRnorm(data[(i-t):(i-1)] ,alpha)     #failure source
violations[i]=(loss[i] > ValueatRisk[i])
}

outputtheo=(1-alpha)*(length(data)-t) 
print(outputtheo)
outputreal=sum(violations)
print(outputreal)
```

I want to combine these graphics. It seems to be a scaling problem, I tried qplot, ggplot and so on without success.

```
graph1=plot(loss[(t+1):length(data)], type="l", col="blue")
graph2=plot(ValueatRisk[(t+1):length(data)], type="l", col="red")
```

How to bring them together in one plot?

Comment: By "rolling", do you mean to calculate VaR on a moving window of returns?

Comment: Yes, the VaR should be like an upper boundry of a series of returns. So that I can later cound count how often this boundry was violated. It should result in a picture like  http://pubs.sciepub.com/ijefm/2/5/4/image/fig8.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If plotting is the only issue now, I think this will produce what you want.

```
plot(loss[(t+1):length(data)], type="l", col="blue")
lines(ValueatRisk[(t+1):length(data)], type="l", col="red")
```

(And BTW, your code won't run as is because `VatRnorm()` inside the loop is really the old/original `VatR()`.)